# Create a box with text over an image in a grid

Tags: css, image, grid, css-float

I'm trying to create a grid view of 12 images in 3 columns with a text box overlay at the bottom of each. I had my grid working perfectly until I tried to put the text box on top. I have a feeling that the box with text should be a child of the image, but I'm not sure how to do that.

I've currently only applied the classes to the first image in attempt to get it working before moving onto the others. I've also got an issue with trying to get the text aligned in the middle of the box. If anyone could help me with either/both of these issues it would be much appreciated!

This is my css:

```
section{
width: 940px;   
min-height: 400px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 10px 0 0 0;    
}

.grid-large {
margin: 16px 0 0 16px;
float: left;
}

.transbox {
height: 50px;
width: 300px;
margin-top: -50px;
background-color:#362e26;
opacity:0.8;
filter:alpha(opacity=80); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}

.category-label{
color: #fff;
margin: 0;
margin-left: 15px;
margin-top: 5px;
vertical-align: middle;
}

.first {
margin-left: 0;
}
```

and my html:

```
<section>
<img src="./images/gowns.jpg" width ="300" height="300" class="grid-large.first">
<div class="transbox">
<p class="category-label">wedding gowns</p> 
</div>
<img src="./images/bridesmaid.jpg" width ="300" height="300" class="grid-large">
<img src="./images/menswear.jpg" width ="300" height="300" class="grid-large">

<img src="./images/venues.jpg" width ="300" height="300" class="grid-large.first">
<img src="./images/planners.jpg" width ="300" height="300" class="grid-large">
<img src="./images/photographers.jpg" width ="300" height="300" class="grid-large">
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would make the image a background image of the div which should contain the text label instead of trying to put a div on top of the image. Inside the div which has the background image you can add new div's with text and place them anywhere you want on the image.

Something like this:

```
<div id="picturegrid">
    <div id="gowns">
        <p>Wedding gowns<p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And

```
#gowns { 
background: center transparent url(./images/gowns.jpg) no-repeat; 
}
```

This link might also help you: http://web.enavu.com/tutorials/making-image-overlay-caption-using-css/

Comment: This is great, thanks! When should images be in html, and when should I try to include them in the css?

Comment: Well I almost always use css to position my images. But in really simple cases where there is no need to specially style/position the image, I would use html.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a JSFiddle that I think answers your requirements: http://jsfiddle.net/ZPcHc/

HTML:

```
<section>
<div class="row">
    <div class="imgbox"><div class="img"><div class="text">text</div></div></div>
    <div class="imgbox"><div class="img"><div class="text">text</div></div></div>
    <div class="imgbox"><div class="img"><div class="text">text</div></div></div>
    <div class="imgbox"><div class="img"><div class="text">text</div></div></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="imgbox"><div class="img"><div class="text">text</div></div></div>
    <div class="imgbox"><div class="img"><div class="text">text</div></div></div>
    <div class="imgbox"><div class="img"><div class="text">text</div></div></div>
    <div class="imgbox"><div class="img"><div class="text">text</div></div></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="imgbox"><div class="img"><div class="text">text</div></div></div>
    <div class="imgbox"><div class="img"><div class="text">text</div></div></div>
    <div class="imgbox"><div class="img"><div class="text">text</div></div></div>
    <div class="imgbox"><div class="img"><div class="text">text</div></div></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="imgbox"><div class="img"><div class="text">text</div></div></div>
    <div class="imgbox"><div class="img"><div class="text">text</div></div></div>
    <div class="imgbox"><div class="img"><div class="text">text</div></div></div>
    <div class="imgbox"><div class="img"><div class="text">text</div></div></div>
</div>
</section
```

CSS:

```
section{
width: 940px;   
min-height: 400px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 10px 0 0 0;    
}

.imgbox{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.img{
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: red;
}

.text{
    position: relative;
    bottom: -50px; /*height of your image*/
    left: 12px;
}
```

You might want to look at pre-made CSS that has grids already implemented like [twitter-bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) or [foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/)

Once you learn the gist of these, you can develop websites much faster! Best of luck

Comment: What gets written in the row class?

Comment: The row class is there to make a horizontal division in your page. Anything you want to be in about the same grouping along the page horizontally you'd want to put inside of a row div. Check out the [bootstrap gridsystem](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) for more information.